# Open a lightbox with long text, and anchor link to section in the text

Tags: jquery, anchor, lightbox

I have a lightbox with a long text, and I would like to be able to use anchor links to open the lightbox, and this way go to different sections of the text.

Hope someone can help! :)

Something like

```
<a href="#section1">Link1</a>
<a href="#section2">Link1</a>

<div class="lightbox">
<div id="section1">
Hello world
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="section2">
Hello again world
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "go to different sections"? Do you want to display only the specified selection or you want to scroll to the anchor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to the anchor, then I would suggest to use fancyBox3, like so:

## 1 Create links:

```
<a href="#test" data-fancybox data-anchor="#section1">Link1</a>
<a href="#test" data-fancybox data-anchor="#section2">Link2</a>
```

## 2 Create your inline content:

```
<div id="test" style="display:none;width:300px;">
  <div id="section1">
    Hello world
  </div>
  <div style="height: 500px;background: #ccc;"></div>
  <div id="section2">
    Hello again world
  </div>
</div>
```

## 3 Use callback to find anchor and scroll to the top position:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  afterShow: function(instance, current) {
    var top = $( current.opts.$orig.data('anchor') ).position().top - 24;

    current.$slide.animate({ scrollTop: top }, 200 );
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LOzEOj?editors=1010